# How to simplify on change function with CSS class index

Tags: jquery, indexing

**Question:** How can I simplify the (working) jQuery function below so I can use it for an infinite number of options in the select field?

**Explanation:** This function shows/hides elements based on the selected option in the select field.

**Example:** If I want to use "select-element-20", how can I change this jQuery function without creating an if statement for each possible option within the select field?

I think I need some solution/variable that indexes the numbers at the end of each option value.

**HTML**

```
<select class="conditional-element-selector">
    <option value="select-element-1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="select-element-2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="select-element-3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="select-element-4">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('select.conditional-element-selector').on('change', function() {

    var val = $(this).val();

    if (val == 'select-element-1') {
      $('.conditional-element-1').toggleClass("hide-conditional-element");
      $('[class*=conditional-element-]:not(.conditional-element-selector):not(.conditional-element-1)').addClass("hide-conditional-element");
    }

    if (val == 'select-element-2') {
      $('.conditional-element-2').toggleClass("hide-conditional-element");
      $('[class*=conditional-element-]:not(.conditional-element-selector):not(.conditional-element-2)').addClass("hide-conditional-element");
    }

    if (val == 'select-element-3') {
      $('.conditional-element-3').toggleClass("hide-conditional-element");
      $('[class*=conditional-element-]:not(.conditional-element-selector):not(.conditional-element-3)').addClass("hide-conditional-element");
    }

    if (val == 'select-element-4') {
      $('.conditional-element-4').toggleClass("hide-conditional-element");
      $('[class*=conditional-element-]:not(.conditional-element-selector):not(.conditional-element-4)').addClass("hide-conditional-element");
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that changes between the conditions is the number in the class. As such you can use the `selectedIndex` of the chosen `option` to target that element, like this:

```js
$('select.conditional-element-selector').on('change', function() {
  var targetIndex = this.selectedIndex + 1;
  $('.conditional-element-' + targetIndex).toggleClass("hide-conditional-element");
  $('[class*=conditional-element-]:not(.conditional-element-selector, .conditional-element-' + targetIndex + ')').addClass("hide-conditional-element");
});
```

Note that you can supply multiple selectors to `:not()` by separating them with a comma.

I would also suggest using a common class on all the target elements which you can use instead of `[class*=conditional-element-]`.

Finally, if all the `conditional-element-N` classes are incremental and align with the indexes of the `option` elements then you can get rid of the classes entirely and relate the elements by their index, which gives you much simpler and cleaner code. Something like this:

```js
$('select.conditional-element-selector').on('change', function() {
  $('.conditional-element').hide().eq(this.selectedIndex).show();
}).trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="conditional-element-selector">
  <option value="select-element-1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="select-element-2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="select-element-3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="select-element-4">Option 4</option>
</select>

<div class="conditional-element">Element 1</div>
<div class="conditional-element">Element 2</div>
<div class="conditional-element">Element 3</div>
<div class="conditional-element">Element 4</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("select.conditional-element-selector").on("change", function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  const id = val.split("-")[2] // select-element-1 => 1
  $(`.conditional-element-${id}`).toggleClass("hide-conditional-element");
    $(
      `[class*=conditional-element-]:not(.conditional-element-selector):not(.conditional-element-${id})`
    ).addClass("hide-conditional-element");
});
```

```js
$(".conditional-element").hide(); // hide all
$("select.conditional-element-selector").on("change", function() {
  $(".conditional-element").hide();
  if (this.value != "Select") {
    $(".conditional-element")
      .eq(this.selectedIndex - 1)
      .show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <select class="conditional-element-selector">
        <option default>Select</option>
        <option value="val1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="val2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="val3">Option 3</option>
        <option value="val4">Option 4</option>
    </select>
    <div class="conditional-element">Element 1</div>
    <div class="conditional-element">Element 2</div>
    <div class="conditional-element">Element 3</div>
    <div class="conditional-element">Element 4</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have gone with the other comment/solution but used your split function for something else, this has helped me a lot.